# AdMob shows only test ads

Tags: android, admob

I recently uploaded my first application to Play Store, a link to my application with the services of admoob, but for some reason only test ads appear and not real and I'm sure everything is correct with the code I also applied to google to check the application and nothing changed

Comment: Inside emulator you can see only test ads

Comment: meaning the normal application in the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. My app which was also showing the test ads only, I did two things:

1. Set up the ad-apps.txt in Admob
2. After my app got "reviewed" and "published" in Play store, the app started showing live-ads.
   Until the time it was in "being reviewed", it used to show test-ads.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have updated the ad-mob app ids to the  correct value from your account and not the one which was used for test-ads.
I assume you would have done this, check your app from another device or ask your friends to download and see what they see. If they see the real ads, it would mean Google has stored your device id as test device for your app.